# Flying on Easyjet with a recently broken arm - what paperwork (if any) is needed?

Tags: health, paperwork, easyjet

Someone I know managed to break their arm on Monday, and is off on holiday next week. Other than concerns about having one arm pasty-white while the other tans, and how to enjoy a beach holiday with one arm in plaster, there's also the question of proving they're OK to fly.

My friend did ask the hospital about flying, whilst getting the plaster put on, and was told "by next week you'll be fine to fly with this cast on". So, from a medical perspective, they should be fine. However, that was only a verbal OK, nothing written.

As a few questions here around Easyjet and intra-Schengen flight ID has taught me, Easyjet can sometimes be stricter on rules / documents than some other airlines. Discovering this WRT plaster casts when about to fly off on holiday isn't the ideal time...

Thus the query - what, if any, paperwork / documentation / doctors notes / pre-approvals / etc does my friend need to be able to fly with Easyjet with an arm in plaster > 7 days after breaking their arm?

Comment: AFAIK, It is ok to fly with a broken arm, as long as the person is not sitting next to an emergency exit..

Comment: I flew Easyjet from Toulouse to Gatwick a few days after busting my arm and nothing was said to me. I was physically unable to lift my bag into the overhead and required assistance of the cabin crew, and still nothing was said. This was 2009, but I'd be surprised if this changed.

Comment: @NeanDerThal The reason that a medical certificate is required is that in the case of a very fresh (<48 hours) cast, there is a risk of trapped gases expanding between the cast and the body during the flight, which may restrict the flow of blood through the outer blood vessels. The solution is to split the cast. http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/2373.aspx?CategoryID=70

Answer (score 2):

I would get a medical certificate to be safe but it would generally be accepted to be ok. There is usually a nominal charge but it is well worth it for the piece of mind alone.

Speak with your Orthopaedic Outpatient department for more real-life instructions. My wife is an Ortho Nurse and regularly recommends the temporary splitting of casts for lower limbs but not sure on the recourse for upper limbs.

In these sorts of situations it is always best to ask for the advice of the professionals.